# Dúvida com checkbox value true e checked

Tags: html

Eu tenho um formulário e para atualizar eu tenho esse trecho de código.
Não consigo entender o que ele quer dizer. Tipo, se o aluno não está ativo no sistema ele coloca como value="true"?
Senão ele também coloca como value="true" mas o checked="checked". O que isso quer dizer?

```
    <%if(aluno.getAtivo() == false){ %>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" value="true"/><br>
    <%}else { %>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" value="true" checked="checked"/><br>
    <%} %>      
    <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
```

Segue página jsp completa:

```
<%@page import="DAO.AlunoDAO"%>
<%@page import="MODEL.Aluno"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Atualizando aluno</title>
</head>
<body>
<% Aluno aluno = new AlunoDAO().find(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")));%>

<form action="alunoCONTROLLER" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="operacao" value="atualizar">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%=aluno.getId()%>">

    <label for="name">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" value="<%=aluno.getNome()%>"/><br/>

    <label for="telefone">Telefone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="telefone" name="telefone" value="<%=aluno.getTelefone() %>"/><br/>

    <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<%=aluno.getEmail()%>" /><br>

    <label for="endereco">Endereço:</label>
    <input type="text" id="endereco" name="endereco" value="<%=aluno.getEndereco() %>"/><br>

    <label for="matricula">Matricula</label>
    <input type="text" id="matricula" name="matricula" value="<%=aluno.getMatricula() %>"/><br>

    <label for="idade">Idade</label>
    <input type="text" id="idade" name="idade" value="<%=aluno.getIdade() %>"/><br>

    <label for="ativo">Ativo:</label>

    <%if(aluno.getAtivo() == false){ %>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" value="true"/><br>
    <%}else { %>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" value="true" checked="checked"/><br>
    <%} %>      
    <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">     
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sua dúvida tem relação com HTML e não com JSP.

**Não confunda value=true com checked.**

Embora possa ser confuso, o atributo `value` não está definindo se o checkbox está marcado ou não na interface com usuário. Este atributo é utilizado para definir o que será recebido no servidor quando uma requisição HTTP POST for feita (obviamente o servidor só recebe se o checkbox estiver marcado).

O atributo que controla o estado do checkbox na interface com o usuário é o checked. Existem duas maneiras de utilizá-lo:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" value="true" checked="checked"/>
```

ou

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ativo" name="ativo" value="true" checked/>
```

Portanto, o código que você postou está correto. Quando `aluno.getAtivo() == true`, você renderiza um checkbox com o atributo `checked` e `value=true`. Quando `aluno.getAtivo() == false`, você renderiza o checkbox sem o atributo checked, mas com `value` também igual `true`. Isso é feito, pois se o usuário clicar no checkbox e enviar, será recebido `true` no servidor, o que é coerente com o seu problema.

Veja outro  exemplo abaixo para entender melhor.

```
<form action="form_demonstracao" method="get">
  <input type="checkbox" name="veiculo" value="Bicicleta"> Eu tenho uma bicicleta<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="veiculo" value="Carro" checked> Eu tenho um carro<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Se o form acima for submetido da maneira que está, o servidor receberá o seguinte:

```
veiculo=Carro
```

Caso o checkbox bicicleta seja marcado, então o seguinte será recebido:

```
veiculo=Carro&veiculo=Bicicleta
```

Comment: Mas a página se chama atualizar.jsp Não entendi por quê não posso chaamr de jsp...

Comment: Não entendi isso: veiculo=Carro&veiculo=Bicicleta

Comment: Não seria: veiculo=Bicicleta?

Comment: Olá @AlineGonzaga. Não entendi. Eu apenas disse que sua dúvida é de HTML puramente, não tem relação com JSP. Pelo que li da sua pergunta, você está com duvida no significado dos atributos de um input checkbox.

Comment: veiculo=Bicicleta é o que foi recebido do lado do servidor. Só é recebido se o checkbox estiver marcado. Note que no primeiro exemplo, apenas o checkbox carro está marcado, então recebe apenas veiculo=Carro. Depois eu comento que o checkbox Bicicleta foi marcado, então é recebeido do lado do servidor veiculo=Carro&veiculo=Bicicleta, pois os dois checkboxes estão marcados. Quando eu falo do lado do servidor, pode ser PHP, JAVA, C#, qualquer linguagem WEB.

Comment: Esse Bicicleta é um atributo de alguma classe em java?

Comment: @AlineGonzaga, então melhor não marcar a resposta como correta. Eu coloquei a tag HTML e certamente vai encontrar alguém que vai te dar uma outra explicação. Isso é importante no SOpt. Muitas vezes o conhecimento está em várias respostas.

Comment: @AlineGonzaga, meu objetivo principal foi mostrar pra você que o valor do atributo value não tem relação com o estado do checkbox (marcado ou desmarcado). O value pode ser o que você quiser. Pode ser inclusive o valor de um atributo de um objeto Java. No seu caso, como você está falando de Aluno ativo, o true é o mais correto. No exemplo que postei, true já não serve, pois estamos falando de carro.

Comment: Não, vou estudar o que tu escreveu depois direito. Valeu a juda.

Comment: No caso ali do seu exemplo então os dois estariam marcados?

Comment: No exemplo, apenas um está marcado, o Carro, pois ele tem o atributo checked. Note que desse jeito, o servidor recebe apenas veiculo=Carro. Logo depois eu cito que cliquei na Bicicleta. Como agora os dois estão marcados, então o servidor recebe veiculo=Carro&veiculo=Bicicleta.

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH Agora entendi. Até que enfim...